# Laravel - Counting a collection of models

Tags: php, laravel, collections

I'm trying to get the count of different models and list them by company.

I have a collection of different models.

```
public function listAllRequets()
{
        $requests = collect();
        $terms = Termination::with('user.company')->where('default_status', 2)->get();
        $deacs = LoaDeactivation::with('user.company')->where('manager_status', 2)->get();
        $reacs = LoaReactivation::with('user.company')->where('manager_status', 2)->get();

        // Use push() to collect them all in one collection
        foreach ($terms as $term)
            $requests->push($term);
        foreach ($deacs as $deac)
            $requests->push($deac);
        foreach ($reacs as $reac)
            $requests->push($reac);

        return $requests;
}
```

In my index function I'm adding them to `$requests`.
To get the list of companies I'm grouping them using the `groupBy()` method.

```
public function index() 
{

    $requests = $this->listAllRequets();

    $requestCompanies = $requests->groupBy(function($requests) {
        return $requests->user->company->company_acronym;
    });
```

In my view I have this:

```
<table class="table table-sm">
    <thead class="thead-light">
        <tr>
            <th>Company</th>
            <th class="text-center">Terms</th>
            <th class="text-center">Deacs</th>
            <th class="text-center">Reacs</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach ($requestCompanies as $company => $requests)
        <tr>
            <td class="pt-3"><strong>{{ $company }}</strong></td>
            @foreach ($requests as $request)
                <td class="text-center">{{ $request-> }}</td>
            @endforeach
        </tr>  
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I need a way to get the count of each model by company.
My companies list out as expected but I'm not sure how to get the correct model count.

Comment: If you have relationships among your company and each request model (Termination, LoaDeactivation, LoaReactivation), wouldn't be easier to do that with a query? That seems a nice usecase for with count method that eloquent provides

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have relationships among your company and each request model (Termination, LoaDeactivation, LoaReactivation), wouldn't be easier to do that with a query at database level?
That seems a nice use case for with count method that eloquent provides:

Assuming the relations in the company model are called `terminations`, `deactivations` and `reactivations`, you could do:

```php
public function index() 
{
    $companies = Company::withCount('terminations','deactivations','reactivations')->get();

    // here pass $companies array to your view
}
```

Then in your view you can access the count for each type on each company:

```php
<table class="table table-sm">
    <thead class="thead-light">
        <tr>
            <th>Company</th>
            <th class="text-center">Terms</th>
            <th class="text-center">Deacs</th>
            <th class="text-center">Reacs</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach ($companies as $company)
        <tr>
            <td class="pt-3"><strong>{{ $company->name }}</strong></td>
            <td class="text-center">{{ $company->terminations_count }}</td>
            <td class="text-center">{{ $company->deactivations_count }}</td>
            <td class="text-center">{{ $company->reactivations_count }}</td>
        </tr>  
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Wow! I was really over thinking this one. So simple, thanks!